# Javascript toggle click off

Tags: javascript, hide, expand

I am working on adding several expanding divs to a page, but am running into trouble getting the divs to automatically collapse when another expands. Here is the script that I am working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
            if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The argument to `.toggle()` isn't a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
        var selected = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $(".tab").not(selected).hide();
        selected.toggle();
    });
});
```

Replace `.tab` with the class you use for your expandable DIVs.